# Why isn't Mapbox viz styled how it is in projects?

Tags: vector, mapbox

When using the Mapbox "Projects" editor, I'm finding the previews do not style the same as the end results on the page. Is anyone experiencing similarly?

In Projects, my map looks like on the left. On the right is how the project appears when visualized:

[image]

Interestingly, on the Projects page, the preview looks like the visualization on the right. It appears like this:

[image]

Does anyone know what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you "hide" the Land layer. Mapbox uses a white layer for land if it is "hidden."

The solution is to "show" the Land layer. Then choose the color you looked for originally in the map to style the Land layer. The final map will look as desired.